# APK не устанавливается

Tags: android

До этого у меня такой ошибки не бывало. У меня APK подписанный, но когда делаю Build и отправляю файл APK на физическое устройство с помощью Гугл Диск, то он просто доходит до конца загрузки и просто "Приложение не установлено". Повторюсь, у меня приложение подписанное, Clean Project и Rebuild делал. Большинство из всего что написано на просторах интернета уже перепробовал, ничего не помогает. Если запустить через "Run", то работает отлично. Если от меня будут нужны какие то еще данные, напишите в ответ и я отправлю, т.к в данный момент я не знаю из-за чего это может быть

Build Gradle(Module App)

```
  plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('')
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('')
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.bendida.eduapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bendida.eduapplication"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules. pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0"))
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}
```

Build Gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
}
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Comment: Читайте в logcat почему не установлено

Comment: Разве, чтобы в LogCat ошибка появилась, телефон не должен быть подключен к Андроид студио по USB?

Comment: в LogCat только показываются ошибки, которые возникают в эмуляторе или же если я подключу к андроид студио телефон по USB, но проблема возникает именно когда я без присоединения устанавливаю APK. Если я с помощью USB установлю, то проблем никаких нет

Comment: Так. я кое как нашел вот такую ошибку

Installation failed due to: 'Failed to commit install session 76867471 with command package install-commit 76867471. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.bendida.eduapplication attempting to redeclare permission com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID already owned by com.google.android.gms'

Comment: Если удалить этот Permission, всё работает идеально. Но без него Google Play не примут приложение

Comment: Я нашел решение проблемы, я в манифесте заменил <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" /> на <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>